# How can I sort my table with elements and subelements

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table similar to this:

```
ID    elementName  subElementOfID

1        1            
2        2            
3        4            
4        5            
5        9            
6        3            
7        6            
8        7            
9       71            8
10       8            
11      10            
12      72            8
13      73            8
```

The elements are not necessarily numeric but can be varchars. The column "subElementOfID" means that this element ("71" for example) is a subelement of the element with ID X. In this example the elements with the IDs 9, 12 and 13 are subelements of the element with ID 8.

Target:

Ordering this table in numeric or alphanumeric order (that depends but is not really important) with the Elements marked as subelements sorted directly under their parent elements. The SELECT output ordered in numeric order in this case should look like:

```
ID    elementName  subElementOfID

 1        1            
 2        2            
 6        3            
 3        4            
 4        5            
 7        6            
 8        7            
 9       71            8
12       72            8
13       73            8
10        8            
 5        9            
11       10
```

The output is processed later in PHP. I would prefer though not to use a PHP solution but a SQL-Select which gives me the table in the right order.

Any help or advice is very much appreciated.

Since this is my first Stackoverflow question I hope I have collected all important facts and am prepared to provide further information :-)

Ralph

---

I found a solution involving a SELF JOIN and a UNION. This may be overly complicated and I would very much like an easier SELECT.

```
SELECT ID, element FROM 
((SELECT t1.ID, t1.elementName as element, t2.elementName AS element2, t1.subElementOfID 
FROM test t1
LEFT JOIN test t2 ON t2.ID = t1.subElementOfID
WHERE t1.subElementOfID IS NOT NULL)

UNION

(SELECT ID, elementName AS element, elementName AS element2, subElementOfID FROM test 
WHERE subElementOfID IS NULL)

ORDER BY element2, subElementOfID, element) tu
```

---

User xpda (thanks for your input!) suggested to order by a string concatenation. This is actually a great idea I think, if the elementName column actually contains a name and not a number, because I'm not totally content with alphanumeric ordering of numbers.
In real live I have integers in this column but may convince my boss to use verbal names not numbers. Trying to write a SQL expression out of my understanding of xpda's answer:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.elementName, t1.subElementOfID AS parentName
FROM test2 t1
LEFT JOIN test2 t2 ON t1.subElementOfID=t2.ID
ORDER BY IF(ISNULL(t2.elementName), t1.elementName, CONCAT(CAST(t2.elementName AS CHAR), CAST(t1.elementName AS CHAR)));
```

So all child elements are ordered under their parents but "10" is naturally between 1 and 2...

Any further suggestions?

Comment: See [this site](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) for many recipes for processing hierarchical data in MySQL.

Comment: That site is interesting! And it helped at least insofar as the expression "self join" triggered my brain to find a working solution :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'm going to answer my own question :-) The comment from Barmar helped as well as the answer from xpda. They didn't provide SQL but lead me in the right direction. Thank your very much!

I have two working solutions, each with it's merrits:

1. I make a simple self join and order by a concatenated string which I enrich with some leading zeros for single digit numbers. In other cases - when sorting varchar values - these zeros are not necessary:

   ```
   SELECT t1.ID, t1.elementName, t1.subElementOfID AS parentName
   FROM table t1
   LEFT JOIN table t2 ON t1.subElementOfID=t2.ID
   ORDER BY IF(ISNULL(t2.elementName), LPAD(t1.elementName, 2, '0'), CONCAT(CAST(LPAD(t2.elementName, 2, '0') AS CHAR), CAST(t1.elementName AS CHAR)));
   ```
2. The SQL from above with self join and UNION works fine even if it's a bit longish:

   ```
   SELECT ID, element FROM 
   ((SELECT t1.ID, t1.elementName as element, t2.elementName AS element2, t1.subElementOfID 
   FROM table t1
   LEFT JOIN table t2 ON t2.ID = t1.subElementOfID
   WHERE t1.subElementOfID IS NOT NULL)

   UNION

   (SELECT ID, elementName AS element, elementName AS element2, subElementOfID FROM table
   WHERE subElementOfID IS NULL)

   ORDER BY element2, subElementOfID, element) tu
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can sort on (order by) a concatenation of the two columns, the second column + first column. You may need to convert to string first.

Comment: If I'm not missing anything, that approach sort of works if I'm content with wrong numeric ordering :-) I tried to write a SQL expression and appended it to my question above.